# Change A File's Build Action Attribute By Team Build 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce, tfsbuild

I have got a project that we publish via ClickOnce; and this project contains some DLL's for localization. But as you know these DLL's are not directly referenced to the project. They are in a separeted folder in the project.

Because of Code Analysis warnings we configured these files' Build Action attribute to None.
But if publish while their Build Action = None, as you guess Visual Studio doesn't include them in to the package. So before we start publish, we change their Build Action attribute to Content.

But now, i want to publish via Team Build 2010; so Team Build will create ClickOnce package. However i couldn't find the way to change Build Action attribute of a file.

Is there any possible way of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution with using Condition attribute.

The project file contains solution items according to their Build Action property.
For example,
if file's Build Action = None, project file contains it like this

```
<None Include="MyRequiredAssembly.dll" />
```

Otherwise, if file's Build Action =  Content it looks like this

```
<Content Include="MyRequiredAssembly.dll" />
```

All of these files are groupped into `<ItemGroup>` and ItemGroup tag has Condition attribute.
So i decided to use Condition to change Build Action property like this.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Publish|AnyCPU'">
    <Content Include="MyRequiredAssembly.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Publish|AnyCPU'">
 <None Include="MyRequiredAssembly.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I hope this helps you too.